# g++: Use ZIP files as input

Tags: c++, boost, annotations, g++

We have the Boost library in our side. It consists of a huge number of files which never change and only a tiny portion of it is used. We swap the whole boost directory if we are changing versions. Currently we have the Boost sources in our SVN, file by file which makes the checkout operations very slow, especially on Windows.

It would be nice if there were a notation / plugin to address C++ files inside ZIP files, something like:

```
// @ZIPFS ASSIGN 'boost' 'boost.zip/boost'
#include <boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp>
```

Are there any support for compiler hooks in g++? Are there any effort regarding ZIP support? Other ideas?

Comment: If you are using `g++`, why not use `gzip` to match? Haha bad joke, +1.

Comment: Move away from SVN to a modern SCM system? Or you could zip the boost directory up to put into SVN to make it faster to checkout, and then have part of the build process be unzipping that file if necessary.

Comment: @bames53 Thought about it. It would not save much time on windows, because of the extraction of many small files. Surely, it would be somewhat better.

Comment: A slightly better approach would be to store the boost.zip in your repository and have your buildsystem extract that file on demand (and obviously svn-ignoring the extracted files/directories).

Comment: In linux there is the FUSE, which can mount many things to some directory (including zip). May be there is FUSE for windows or similar user-space mounting tool.

Comment: @niko We use some hundreds of files from Boost (many thousand files). Can you tell a build system that finds the files needed for us automatically, based on the net of the `#include` directives? Should we write something for it?

Comment: @Notinlist i'm not sure what the question in your last comment is, and how it relates to the original question?

Comment: @niko You said that "extract that file on demand". So I asked "Can you tell a build system that finds the files needed for us automatically, ...". Then I asked: [if there is no such thing] Should we write something for it? It's all perfectly in context.

Comment: @Notinlist sorry, what i meant was: Extract all the files as part of your build process. Which is what barnes53 already mentioned in the second part of his comment, which i apparently did not read correctly (sorry). I don't think that there is a build system that transparently handles .zip files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume that `make` or a similar buildsystem is involved in the process of building your software. I'd put the zip file in the repository, and add a rule to the Makefile to extract it before the actual build starts.

For example, suppose your zip file is in the source tree at "external/boost.zip", and it shall be extracted to "external/boost", and it contains at its toplevel a file "boost_version.h".

```
# external/Makefile
unpack_boost: boost/boost_version.h

boost/boost_version.h: boost.zip
    unzip $<
```

I don't know the exact syntax of the `unzip` call, ask your manpage about this.

Then in other Makefiles, you can let your source files depend on the `unpack_boost` target in order to have `make` unpack Boost before a source file is compiled.

```
# src/Makefile (excerpt)
unpack_boost:
    make -C ../external unpack_boost

source_file.cpp: unpack_boost
```

If you're using a Makefile generator (or an entirely different buildsystem), please check the documentation for these programs for how to create something like the custom target `unpack_boost`. For example, in CMake, you can use the [add_custom_command](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:add_custom_command) directive.

*The fine print:* The `boost/boost_version.h` file is not strictly necessary for the Makefile to work. You could just put the `unzip` command into the `unpack_boost` target, but then the target would effectively be phony, that is: it would be executed during each build. The file inbetween (which of course you need to replace by a file which is actually present in the zip archive) ensures that `unzip` only runs if necessary.

Answer (score 7):

A year ago I was in the same position as you. We kept our source in SVN and, even worse, included boost in the same repository (same branch) as our own code. Trying to work on multiple branches was impossible, as it would take most of a day to check-out a fresh working copy. Moving boost into a separate vendor repository helped, but it would still take hours to check-out.

I switched the team over to git. To give you an idea of how much better it is than SVN, I have just created a repository containing the boost 1.45.0 release, then cloned it over the network. (Cloning copies all of the repository history, which in this case is a single commit, and creates a working copy.)

That clone took six minutes.

In the first six seconds a compressed copy of the repository was copied to my machine. The rest of the time was spent writing all of those tiny files.

I heartily recommend that you try git. The learning curve is steep, but I doubt you'll get much pre-compiler hacking done in the time it would take to clone a copy of boost.

Answer (score 4):

We've been facing similar issues in our company. Managing boost versions in build environments is never going to be easy. With 10+ developers, all coding on their own system(s), you will need some kind of automation.

First, I don't think it's good idea to store copies of big libraries like boost in SVN or any SCM system for that matter, that's not what those systems are designed for, except if you plan to modify code in boost yourself. But let's assume you're not doing that.

Here's how we manage it now, after trying lots of different methods, this works best for us.

For every version of boost that we use, we put the whole tree (unzipped) on a file server and we add extra subdirectories, one for each architecture/compiler-combination, where we put the compiled libraries.
We keep copies of these trees on every build system and in the global system environment we add variables like:

```
BOOST_1_48=C:\boost\1.48 # Windows environment var
```

or

```
BOOST_1_48=/usr/local/boost/1.48 # Linux environment var, e.g. in /etc/profile.d/boost.sh
```

This directory contains the boost tree (boost/*.hpp) and the added precompiled libs (e.g. lib/win/x64/msvc2010/libboost_system*.lib, ...)

All build configurations (vs solutions, vs property files, gnu makefiles, ...) define an internal variable, importing the environment vars, like:

```
BOOSTROOT=$(BOOST_1_48) # e.g. in a Makefile, or an included Makefile
```

and further build rules all use the BOOSTROOT setting for defining include paths and library search paths, e.g.

```
CXXFLAGS += -I$(BOOSTROOT)
LFLAGS   += -L$(BOOSTROOT)/lib/linux/x64/ubuntu/precise
LFLAGS   += -lboost_date_time
```

The reason for keeping local copies of boost is compilation speed. It takes up quite a bit of disk space, especially the compiled libs, but storage is cheap and a developer losing lots of time compiling code is not. Plus, this only needs to be copied once.

The reason for using global environment vars is that build configurations are transferrable from one system to another, and can thus be safely checked in to your SCM system.

To smoothen things a bit, we've developed a little tool that takes care of the copying and setting the global environment. With a CLI, this can even be included in the build process.

Different working environments mean different rules and cultures, but believe me, we've tried lots of things and finally, we decided to define some kind of convention. Maybe ours can inspire you...

Comment: This is similar to how we do it, except we symlink boost/ to one of the various boost versions that exist.

Comment: That's fine, as long as the file system supports symlinks. We needed a method that works both on Windows and *nix systems.

Answer (score 2):

This is something you would not do in g++, because any other application that wants to do it would also have to be modified.

Store the files on a compressed filesystem.  Then every application gets the benefit automatically.

Comment: If a g++ is not "hooked" like that then the annotation will be ignored and the zip can be extracted manually (as a fallback). Boost does not need to know about all this. On the second: compressed filesystem does not speed up checkout.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible in an OS to allow transparent access to files inside a ZIP file. I know that I put it in the design of my own OS a long time ago (2004 or so) but never got it to a point where it was usable. The downside is that seeking backwards in a file inside a ZIP is slower as it's compressed (and you can't rewind the compressor state, so you have to seek from the start instead). This also makes using a zip-inside-a-zip slow for rewinding and reading. Fortunately, most cases just read a file sequentially.

It should also be retrofittable to current OSes, at least in client space. You can hook the filesystem access functions used (fopen, open, ...) and add a set of virtual file descriptors that your own software would return for a given filename. If it's a real file just pass it on, if it's not open the underlying file (possibly again via this very function) and pass a virtual handle. When accessing the file contents, read directly from the zip file without caching.

On Linux you would use an LD_PRELOAD to inject it into existing software (at usage time), on Windows you can hook the system calls or inject a DLL into the space of software to hook the same functions.

Does anybody know if this already exists? I can't see any clear reason it wouldn't...

Comment: On LINUX there's the FUSE kernel module (Filesystem User Space E-whatever).